# Get position of List Item in Bind View

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a list and the list is dynamically populated using the bindview. I have a checkbox inside each list item and I want the position of the list item when the checkbox in that particular item is checked. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you adding an `OnCheckedListener` at activity level or at view level?

Comment: I am adding onCheckedListener at view level

Comment: well, your list adapter has a [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) method and that supplies the position. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: I am using Cursor Adapter. Does it have a Bind View?

Comment: You mean `SimpleCursorAdapter` maybe? Or have you created your own `CursorAdapter` implementation?

Comment: I have implemented my own CursorAdapter

Comment: Have you overriden `getView`?

Comment: Its not been overrided